# Преобразование char в const char* и обратное преобразование

Tags: c++

```
    double znach(vector<string> &buff)
{
    int kolich = buff.size();
    double znachen(0.0);
    char help;
    for(int i(0); i <= buff.size(); i++)
    {
        help = system(buff[i].c_str());
        znachen += atof(help) * pow(10.0, kolich);
        kolich--;
    }
    return znachen;
}
```

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как char преобразовать в const char*. При использовании atof требуется const char*, но переменная help у меня char. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Данное объявление параметра vector<string> вызывает большие сомнения в его осмысленности. Похоже, вы просто не понимаете, что вы делаете. Так что будет лучше, если вы добавите описание задания.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow vector<string> использую для практики с векторами. функция принимает вектор, в котором записано некоторое число, которое в функции main считывается из файла в вектор. понимаю, что можно было в простой char считывать. но целью было поработать с векторами.

Comment: Тву что содержит каждый элемент вектора? Всего лишь одну цифру?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в векторе содержится набор цифр. в каждой грубо говоря ячейке содержится одна цифра

Comment: Преобразовать, конечно можно, например, `atof((const char *)(long)help)` пройдет, но  работать это не будет. `system()` возвращает число (код возврата исполняемой команды), которое никоим образом не соответствует той строке, которую вы надеетесь получить как результат вызова system

Comment: Откуда тут вообще взялось `atof`? При чем оно здесь?

Comment: @AnT atof использую для преобразования из const char* в double

Answer (score 1):

Похоже вы имеете в виду следующее

```
double znach( const std::vector<std::string> &buff )
{
    double znachen = 0.0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < buff.size(); i++ )
    {
        znachen = 10 * znachen + std::stoi( buff[i] );
    }

    return znachen;
}
```

То есть предполагается, что каждый элемент вектора содержит лишь одну цифру.

Comment: @АлексейГоловнин Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)